# Not handling functions right

Tags: c

My code is supposed to make a simple menu to change the armor of a character.  The code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Armor {
   char chestplate [50];
   char helmet [50];
};

void changeArmor (){
    struct Armor character;
    char a [50];
    printf("Choose a chestplate\n");
    scanf("%s",&a);
    strcpy(character.chestplate,a);
    printf("Choose a helmet\n");
    scanf("%s",&a);
    strcpy(character.helmet,a);
    menu();
}

void checkArmor () {
    struct Armor character;
    printf("Your equipped chestplate is: %s\n", character.chestplate);
    printf("Your equipped helmet is: %s\n", character.helmet);
    menu();
}

void menu () {
    int a;
    printf("What do you want to do?\n");
    printf("1.Change Armor.\n");
    printf("2.Check current armor.\n");
    printf("3.Quit\n");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    if(a==1) changeArmor;   // Oops: should be changeArmor();
    if(a==2) checkArmor;    // Oops: should be checkArmor();
    if(a!=3) menu;          // Oops: maybe this should be menu(); — or …
}

void initializeChar (){
    struct Armor character;
    strcpy(character.chestplate, "Shirt");
    strcpy(character.helmet, "Hat");
}

int main () {
    struct Armor character;
    initializeChar();
    menu();
    return 0;
}
```

When I try to use anything on the menu, the program always exits, instead of running the function called. Is there anything I have been doing wrong in the code?

EDIT: It was the parenthesis. Thanks.

Comment: These: `if(a==1) changeArmor;
    if(a==2) checkArmor;
    if(a!=3) menu;` are not function calls.  You need `changeArmor();` to make that into a function call.  Your compiler is probably warning you about a statement with no effect.  You probably don't want the recursive calls to `menu()` in `changeArmor()` and `checkArmor()` either.  Simply omit them — but create a loop in the `menu()` function, or have `main()` call `menu()` iteratively.

Comment: don't edit the question to fix the code so that there's no problem anymore

Comment: Please do not modify your question to invalidate answers (or comments giving the answer) after you've been given the answer.  It is more or less OK to annotate the necessary changes — or leave the code unchanged and describe the necessary changes, or just select an answer that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you forgot the () meaning that changeArmor() and checkArmor() are functions.

So, when you make your choice it is not doing anything and it continues until it reaches return 0.

Comment: Same for menu as well. It is a function also.

Comment: It is in fact going in the menu once, as it is called in the main function with parenthesis.

Comment: That is inside the main function. But it is not treated as a function inside the menu function.

Answer (score 1):

As already answered by Jonathan Leffler and T. Roncoli you are not really doing function calls. For example menu is not a function call, its just a pointer to your function. Instead you would need to do menu() in order to call the function.

PS:

I would also like to note here that its probably not worth having a recursive menu function as it would only grow your stack memory segment. In realistic systems the stack actually has a limit as to how much it can grow. You could instead just use an iterative solution and just loop until the exit command (a==3) was passed.

People might argue that C does not have the concept of a stack but all compilers on x86 and x64 machines will use the stack for automatic variables and function calls.

It would be a nice to test how much your stack can grow before your program crashes, by constantly giving values that would trigger the menu() function.